# JavaScript location.reload() loops off sync after a certain time, why?

Tags: javascript, location, reload

I've been trying to add some code to the original website php so that there will be an image shown for 25 seconds, then it disappears, the next one is show, and it disappears etc.

On my macbook when testing with the current code (see below), it all seems to work fine, however on the large display in the pub where it is being displayed it begins reloading off sync (not in the loop I want it to if that makes sense).

So what happens now is, the last image that is being displayed disappears, then the first element (another script) is being shown and only a few seconds later the page is being reloaded. The reload should be right after the last image is hidden.

```
<script>
    function displayAds() {
        $("#appjs").remove();           // Haal het app.js script weg zodat deze niet meer draait
        $(".container, .row").hide();   // Verberg de content van het klassement/scoreboard
        $("#ad-slides").show();         // Laat de container met ad-slides zien
        $("#slide-een").show();         // Laat de eerste slide zien

        setTimeout(displayAd2, 25000) // Roep de functie voor het laten zien van slide twee aan

    }

    // Deze functie laat, wanneer aangeroepen, de tweede ad slide zien
    function displayAd2() {
        $("#slide-een").hide();     // Verberg de eerste slide
        $("#slide-twee").show();    // Laat de tweede slide zien

        setTimeout(displayAd3, 25000) // Roep de functie voor het laten zien van slide drie aan
    }

    function displayAd3() {
        $("#slide-twee").hide();    // Verberg de tweede slide
        $("#slide-drie").show();    // Laat de derde slide zien

        setTimeout(hideAds, 25000); // Roep hideAds aan na 25 sec om de ads te verbergen en dus het klassement te tonen
    }

    function hideAds() {
        $(".ads").hide();
        $("#ad-slides").hide();
        var assetsssss = "{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"; // Dit is het app js script nu
        $("body").append('<script src="'+assetsssss+'" id="appjs"></script\>'); // Voeg het app js script toe onderaan de pagina zodat deze weer draait
        $(".container, .row").show();// Maak de score content weer zichtbaar

        //setTimeout(displayAds, 90000)  // Begin de loop weer opnieuw na 90 seconden
        location.reload(true);
    }

    // Hier begint het script
       $(document).ready( function() {
       $("#ad-slides").hide();  // Verberg de ad-slides container
       $(".ads").hide();        // Verberg alle ad slides

       setTimeout(displayAds, 90000); // Roep na 90 sec van het laden van de pagina de functie voor het tonen van de eerste slide aan
    });
</script>
```

So, I don't know why it starts looping off sync after a while. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing an infinitive reload loop each time you reload `locación.reload(true)` is called the page refresh and all the scripts are loading again then the`displayAds` , `displayAds2` so on are executing again because all of them are chainable execution because of `setTimeout` and when you reload the page the function `$.document.ready` it’s executing again. That’s why you are in the reload loop

Answer (score 0):

Javascript timers aren't guaranteed to fire exactly at the time you specify. They fire *as soon as possible afterwards*.

For in depth reading, check out the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: What about a <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="165"> ?

Comment: @OlleDejong it's likely to be even less accurate, as the timing is only in seconds, and there will be a variable network delay as the refresh happens. The whole thing would stay in sync but it seems like a pretty heavy handed approach. Users would be interrupted each time it refreshes as well